# MVC on Server 2008 R2 - How?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a new WIndows Server 2008 R2 x64 DataCentre with Framework 3.5 SP1 and Framework 4 installed. When I install my MVC application (VS 2008 MVC 2.0 using a Web Setup project installer) and browse to the application I get an error that System.Web.Mvc cannot be found. If I copy the relevant DLLs (System.Web.Mvc etc)into the bin directory the app runs up perfectly.

I have checked everywhere for an installer but can only find the VS2008 related bits, no server runtime. How do I get ASP.Net MVC installed in this environment so that we don't have to Copy Local the dlls?

Many thanks
Brian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do a server install which doesn't require Visual Studio installed:

```
msiexec /i AspNetMVC2.msi /l*v .\mvc.log MVC_SERVER_INSTALL="YES"
```

Now you are probably asking where's this `AspNetMVC2.msi` coming from. Actually you download `AspNetMVC2_VS2008.exe` from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en), rename the `.exe` to `.zip` and inside you'll find what you are looking for (in the `mvcruntime` sub-folder).

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but when I attempt to open the resulting .zip file it is invalid. I tyried opening it from Windows Explorer and 7zip. Has this worked for you?

Comment: Aha! It can be opened with WinRAR

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to install ASP.NET MVC2 and register it in IIS.. It's probably one of the most simple ways to install extensions for your server. Just follow this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=185037

Just to be more detailed here.. If you have Platform Installer installed - when you click on the second link (and have platform installer *closed*), a window will pop up, with details about MVC2. It will have an Install button. Just click it, accept the terms and you're done :)
Here's what this window looks like: http://lh5.ggpht.com/_uVsNX7rt1gI/S81ffYtSDBI/AAAAAAAAAIM/3raMs0bomNo/MVC2.PNG

Comment: I had done this as this is where you get led when you look for the server runtime components. However, it did NOT install MVC 2 and I worked through all of the options in some detail

Comment: I've got a live server running Server 2008 R2 x64.. I have just followed the same link, installed MVC2, then went to the website bin directory and deleted System.Web.Mvc.dll there.. (I didn't bother doing it before :) )
Refreshed the page: the website app pool reloaded, and the page loads fine.. Could you try it again? It most definitely works!

Comment: Actually, just going through this process and am confident that it will work. I presume you are refering to the MVC 2 link in the other answer? Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Nope.. I was following the link from my answer :)
I'm sure the other approach by @Darin works as well, and the end result is most likely the same, but I find it easier to use the Platform Installer :)

Comment: Updated the post with a screen shot, just so you know what I mean ^_^