# IIS 7.5 404 not found for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

I've seen many similar situations posted here, but none of which exactly match mine and, unfortunately, none of which had answers that resolved my issue. So, here goes nothing.

For starters, my new MVC frontend and WebAPI projects work just fine when running on my local PC via Visual Studio. The issue is when I try to publish the projects (used multiple methods: msdeploy, ftp, file system copied to server) to the staging server. I know the server is configured correctly because I have several other WebUI(MVC)/WebAPI applications running on the same server, deployed the exact same way, using the exact same technology stack (down to the version). Here is what I've tried so far:

- I have verified that the application is deployed into the correct folder on the server and that the virtual path --> application in IIS is pointed to the correct physical location
- I have verified that the application is set to use a dedicated app pool running in asp.net 4.0 integrated mode under applicationpoolidentity
- The IUSR user and identity for the application pools have been granted read/execute access to the virtual path and all subfolders/files
- I have tried the proposals I have seen here regarding using verb="*" for the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handler in the web.config file but it didn't work
- The IIS log shows the 404 error as 404 0 0 62; looking up the win32 status code (62) provides: "space to store the file waiting to be printed is not available on the server" which does not seem applicable to my situation (retrieved [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx))

Below is a (redacted) copy of the output in the IIS log file:

```
2015-01-16 17:54:59 X.X.X.X GET /Accounts/Alpha/ - 443 - X.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.95+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 0 62
```

This is happening whether I try to access the URL via the server itself (tried FQDN and localhost) or my development machine. There are no errors in the Event Log on the machine relevant to IIS. If anyone could offer some additional insight, I would very much appreciate it as this is driving me up a wall. I don't understand how it could be working for all of the other applications on the server yet I can find no differences in configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it MVC4 or MVC5 application? Your virtual directory is marked to act as an application? Place a simple html file on root of your folder and see if that page is accessible or not.

Comment: MVC4, I'll confirm accessibility with the HTML file in a bit when I reach work

Comment: Yes it is a virtual directory with a child directory marked as an application. Interestingly enough the HTML file wasn't accessible either... after completely removing and re-creating the directory structure it seems to be working. @ImranBalouch if you post as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I am glad that you got it fixed, m not sure either it is good that I post an answer but I am posting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put an html file in the directory and access it, if it can't be accessed than surely there is any issues with your deployment settings or IIS, try by recreating the directory structure :) I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the security was screwed up so I completely removed and re-created the directory structure, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This has bitten me a couple of times.

```
<system.webServer>
    .....
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    .....
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that made no difference. Still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Does the site have bindings for port 80 in IIS or is it just 443?

Comment: It's just 443, and the SSL certificate is valid

Comment: Can you check this thread to see if it helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068770/getting-404-error-on-mvc-web-site